# Return value of function in IF statement shows strange behaviour

Tags: bash

Can anyone explain what is going on here?

Why does an "IF" statement think the return is '1' (not Null) when i say 'Return 0' and the other way round.

I found that out while coding another script, so i developed this small script to test it:

```
#!/bin/bash

function testreturnzero()
{
        echo $1
        return 0
}


function testreturnone()
{
        echo $1
        return 1
}


if (testreturnzero 1) || (testreturnzero 2)
then
        echo "zero returned '1'"
fi


if (testreturnone 1) || (testreturnone 2)
then
        echo "one returned '1'"
fi
```

The IF which refers to the 'return 0' thinks its true (and doesn't process the second function), the IF which refers to 'return 1' thinks its false. Shouldn't it be the exact opposite?

```
1
zero returned '1'
1
2
```

I cant put the return value in a variable as I will have several of those checks.

Comment: In bash, a function returning `0` means `success` and returning a non-zero value means `failure`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf That should be an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash, a function returning `0` means `success` and returning a non-zero value means `failure`. Hence your `testreturnzero` succeeds and your `testreturnone` fails.

Does that help understanding why your `if`s behave that way? (it should!).

The return code of the last executed command/function is stored in the special variable `$?`.

So:

```
testreturnzero 0
ret_testreturnzero=$?
testreturnone 1
ret_testreturnone=$?
echo "$ret_testreturnzero"
echo "$ret_testreturnone"
```

will output (the two last lines):

```
0
1
```

Now you may think of storing them in a variable (as here) and do your logic processing later. But there's a catch `:)`. Because you didn't store `true` and `false` in variables, you stored `0` and `1` (bash can't store booleans in a variable). So to check success or failure later:

```
if ((ret_testreturnzero==0)); then
    echo "testreturnzero succeeded"
fi
```

or

```
if ((ret_testreturnzero!=0)); then
    echo "testreturnzero failed"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

In `bash`, the return code of a function is the same as a external program when you `test` the result.

So for `test`, a valid return code is `0` and an invalid is any other number

so, by doing

```
if ( testreturnone 1 ); then #it is ok
   echo "error"; #it's supposed to happen, not an error
fi
```

You can explicitly test the value to the one you want to clear it up:

```
if [[ "$(testreturnzero 1)" = "1"); then #it is ok if you decide that 1 is the good value
   echo "ok";                            #But absolutly not the bash philosophy
fi
```